# AngularJS + D3 Multiple Directives Used In View Only One Updates

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, d3.js

I have a gauge chart directive that needs to be placed in a view multiple times, but the update method in the controller only appears to update the last directive in the view.  Initially I thought maybe I hadn't set the scope to be an isolate scope having run into that before, but that wasn't the case, and that would have just thrown an error, but the view does load all the charts, but it only updates the one.

I made a [codepen](http://codepen.io/mtpultz/pen/KdOYKv?editors=001) of the directive to help, and I include a basic stub of the directive and controller below. NOTE: only just started using D3 and implementing it in directives so there's an issue that when you resize the browser the directive multiplies (was trying to make it responsive) so you might have hit save after resizing the browser window in the codepen.

```
  .directive('d3Gauge', [
    'D3GaugeConfig',
    function(D3GaugeConfig) {

      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          title: '@chartTitle',
          config: '=chartConfig',
          data: '=chartData'
        },
        link: link,
        template: '<div>{{d3GaugeCtrl.title}}</div>',
        controller: 'D3GaugeController',
        controllerAs: 'd3GaugeCtrl',
        bindToController: true
      };

      function link($scope, $element, $attrs) {
         ...

        // Browser onresize event
        $window.onresize = function() {
          $scope.$apply();
        };

        // Watch for resize event
        $scope.$watch(function() {
          return angular.element($window)[0].innerWidth;
        }, function() {
          render($element, $scope.data);
        });

        $scope.update = update;
      }

      function render(element, newValue) {
         ...
      }

      function update(newValue, newConfiguration) {

         ...
      }
    }
  ])

  .controller('D3GaugeController', [
    '$scope',
    function($scope) {

      var vm = this;

      function updateReadings() {

        // Just pump in random data here...
        if (angular.isDefined($scope.update)) {
          $scope.update(Math.random() * 100);
        }
      }

      // Every few seconds update reading values
      updateReadings();

      setInterval(function() {
        updateReadings();
      }, 5 * 1000);
    }
  ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the last gauge is changing because:

You are storing variable pointer which stores the last path.

```
pointer = pg.append('path')
  .attr('d', pointerLine)
  .attr('transform', 'rotate(' + config.minAngle + ')');
```

So now when you do

```
 pointer
      .duration(config.transitionMs)
      .ease('elastic')
      .attr('transform', 'rotate(' + newAngle + ')');
```

Only the last pointer will get updated with the new transform.

So if you want to update all the gauge path for same random value do:

```
//select all the path in all svg with group class pointer  
d3.selectAll("svg .pointer path").transition()
          .duration(config.transitionMs)
          .ease('elastic')
          .attr('transform', 'rotate(' + newAngle + ')');//update the new angle
```

Working code [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvoNQv?editors=001)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, what if I wanted each to be updating independently is that not possible... Oh I think I see what you're pointing out (no pun intended) since I'm storing the directives values outside the link function they are all sharing these values.  In the app each chart will be independent of the other and updating based on a different data set.  How do you typically setup a D3 directive that is reuseable without having to pass copious function parameters.  Is it possible to wrap directive instances into a service or something?

Comment: Your query _if I wanted each to be updating independently is that not possible_: Yes you can do that by implementing a $watch over a variable.
So when the variable changes the watch will trigger your function where you can update the path.

Comment: But I should remove the variables from the directive and put them in the link function so they aren't being shared though right?  For example, won't svg be referencing only the last directive similar to pointer.

Comment: I have moved the interval and update function inside the render so now it works as expected check http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvoNQv?editors=001

Comment: One more bug in your code when you resize you call the render method...but inside your render method you are appending svg and components...so on resize you will find your gauge number increasing.

Comment: To fix this resize bug mentioned above I have made doResize function which will change the svg width and height..and not call the render function.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvoNQv?editors=001